# Map data from an array containing arrays into a component

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I have some large data from an api - https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events

I want to map the coordinates into a component from React Leaflet that displays a marker on a map.

`<Marker position={[LAT, LON]} />`

Each coordinate in the data below has a coordinate - `coordinates: [LAT, LON]`

My data

```json
[
  {
    id: 'EONET_5165',
    title: 'Tropical Cyclone Gati',

    geometries: [
      {
        date: '2020-11-21T18:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [55.5, 10.8],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T00:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [53.8, 10.6],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T06:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [52.5, 10.3],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T12:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [51.5, 10.4],
      },
    ],
  },
{
    id: 'EONET_4445',
    title: 'Tropical Cyclone Susan',

    geometries: [
      {
        date: '2020-11-21T18:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [55.5, 10.8],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T00:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [53.8, 10.6],
      },
}
]
```

I need to map over each event and display a marker for each coordinate

This is the latest thing I have tried. It gives an err because the positions are null.

```js
{events.map((evt) => (
        <Marker
          position={[
            evt.geometries.map((g) => g.coordinates[1]),
            evt.geometries.map((g) => g.coordinates[0]),
          ]}
        />
      ))}
```

I have also tried mapping each coordinates array to but that led to me passing in all the lat and longs into the parameter.

I apologie for the vague question.

Answer (score 1):

can try something like

```
{events.map((evt) => (
       evt.geometries.map(geo=>(
            <Marker
               position={[
                 geo.coordinates[1],
                 geo.coordinates[0]
                   ]}
              />
        ))
    
  ))}
```

Comment: This gives me an error. ```Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, 127.84286499023438,1.6633016286241373,127.84286499023438,1.7379700300000804,127.91641235351562,1.7379700300000804,127.91641235351562,1.6633016286241373,127.84286499023438,1.6633016286241373)```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make a new array, to make it more simple to follow what you want to achieve. I made an example:

```
const example = [
  {
    id: 'EONET_5165',
    title: 'Tropical Cyclone Gati',
    geometries: [
      {
        date: '2020-11-21T18:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [55.5, 10.8],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T00:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [53.8, 10.6],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T06:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [52.5, 10.3],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T12:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [51.5, 10.4],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'EONET_4445',
    title: 'Tropical Cyclone Susan',

    geometries: [
      {
        date: '2020-11-21T18:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [55.5, 10.8],
      },
      {
        date: '2020-11-22T00:00:00Z',
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [53.8, 10.6],
      }
    ]
  }
];

let geometries = [];

example.forEach(item => {
  item.geometries.forEach(geo => {
    geometries = [...geometries, geo.coordinates];
  });
});

console.log(geometries);

geometries.map((geo, i) => (
  <Marker
    key={i}
    position={geo}
  />
)
```